# Next number in the sequence -2 3 27 69 129 ..

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was asked this on an aptitude test recently

> Determine the next number in the sequence: $-2, 3, 27, 69, 129, \ ..$ 
>   A: $178$ 
>   B: $207$ 
>   C: $288$ 
>   D: $312$

I've been racking my brain for a few days trying to find the solution but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: OEIS doesn't have anything. Where did you get this from?

Comment: Define $$f(x) = 14 - \frac{329 x}{12} + \frac{287 x^2}{24} - \frac{7 x^3}{12} + \frac{x^4}{244}$$ Then $(-2,3,27,69,129) = (f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5))$. So naturally the next number is $f(6) = 208$ ;)

Comment: The next number is $42$.  You can't prove me wrong.  But, at the same time you can't prove the person who says the next number is $43$ wrong either, or $44$ for that matter, or $\pi$ or $\sqrt{e-3.4}$ or anything else.  There is simply not enough information to determine the next entry uniquely.

Comment: I got this as a multiple choice question in an aptitude practice test.The options are 178 207 268 312.

Comment: Then whoever wrote the test should be slapped across the face repeatedly unless they include an option for "not enough information" which is always the correct answer.  Such questions are not well formed and do not have any way of answering.

Comment: Take for a simple example: find the next number in the sequence $1,2,4,\dots$.  One could argue that the next number is $8$ since we double the previous (*sequence continuing $1,2,4,8,16,\dots$*).  One could argue that the next number is $5$ since it is the list of all numbers which are not divisible by $3$ (*sequence continuing $1,2,4,5,7,8,10,\dots$*) (*alternatively worded, add one, then add two, then add one, then add two, etc...*)  One could argue for others as well.

Comment: By the very nature that multiple sequences exist with the same starting values but a different "next number" that implies there is not a unique answer.  The same is true for *any* starting entries for a sequence, yours included.

Comment: Thank @JMoravitz for the explanation..

Answer (score 1):

I think most smart comments agree that there is no real mathematical progression to be discovered here. *Unless you may assume typos*

So either this is an aptitude test on how you would solve impossible problems (being able to quickly acknowledge you don't know and able to tell why),

or this could be some tricky calculation where you'd have to transcribe the numbers and count the values of letters and add and/or multiply values, which probably is only valid in the mind of the developer of the test

or this is an aptitude test where the developer of the test failed. Sort of a special case of the previous case.

-- note: I love the '207' answers that make my answer look stupid ;) I'll +1 them. The approach is quite typical for such problems, and the assumption of a typo should be a question but is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The next number would be 207. Look into the differences between terms 
5, 24, 42, 60 
And the difference between these is 
19, 18, 18, 
So i thought the first 19 should be 18 also i. e. Our sequence will be -3, 3, 27, 69, 129, 207, ...

Answer (score 1):

It is $207$ and the OP made a typo
The original sequence is

$-3, 3, 27, 69, 129, 207,\ldots$

$a_n=3 (3 - 7 n + 3 n^2)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}\land n\geq 1$

Hope this helps